# Confusing about the shape of ndarray

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I am a little confused about the shape of 3d ndarray.  The numpy version is 1.24.2.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((10,3,4))

print(a.shape)
print(a[1,:,:].shape)
print(a[1,:,0:4].shape)
print(a[1,:,range(0,4)].shape)
```

The results of the first three outputs were expected: 10,3,4; 3,4; 3,4.  However, the last output was 4,3 which is quite confusing.

Comment: This means you have an array with `10 elements`, each of which is a `3x4 matrix`, and all elements are initialized to zero.

Comment: The last one is just a 4x3 matrix.

Comment: I think the question is, why is `a[1,:,0:4]` and `a[1,:,range(0,4)]` returning a different shaped ndarray